# What is the difference between “anger” and “wrath”?

Tags: greek, word-study, kjv, word-choice

Anger and wrath are listed separately in a list in Colossians 3:8, and Ephesians 4:26 might indicate that there is some difference in Paul’s mind between the term anger and the term wrath.

> Col 3:8 - But now you also put off all these things: **anger, rage**,
> malice, slander, foul language out of your mouth.
>
> Eph 4:26 - Be ye **angry**, and sin not: let not the sun go down upon
> your **wrath**:

My question is this: is there a difference in Paul’s mind between anger and wrath?

Comment: The same as between gladness and joy

Comment: Do you mean Ephesians 4: **26**?

Comment: Yes, pardon I did mean 4:26

Comment: ChatGPT says that "*Overall, while both words refer to anger or wrath, "parorgismos" emphasizes a state or condition, while "orgizō" emphasizes the action or expression of anger.*", but it could be making that up just to humour me.

Comment: @ray be encouraged - Chat GPT is trinitarian. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, four different words are involved as follows.  The words in Eph 4:26 and Col 3:8 are different.

**Eph 4:26** "**Be angry**, and yet do not sin." Let not the sun set upon your **wrath**

In this verse the two words are:

- **ὀργίζω** (orgizó = [verb] irritate, provoke, anger), eg, Matt 5:22, 18:34, 22:7, Luke 1:21, 15:28, etc
- **παροργισμός** (parorgismos = [noun] exasperation, wrath, irritation, indignation), only found in Eph 4:26.  Both words come from the same cognate root with παροργισμός being a strengthened, more intense form.

Note that Paul is not condemning anger as such; indeed, the "Be angry" is actually in the imperative case - a command to be angry.  However, Paul is saying we should be angry about righteous causes and not loose control - we should be angry at some things but he provides important caveats:

- do not let you anger develop into wrath, ie, loose control, and,
- do not let your anger last after sunset

**Col 3:8** But now you also put off all these things: **anger**, **rage**, malice, slander, foul language out of your mouth.

In this verse the two words are:

- **ὀργή** (orgé = [noun] anger, wrath, passion; punishment, vengeance), eg, Matt 3:7, Mark 3:5, Luke 3:7, 21:23, John 3:36, etc.  It is the cognate noun with the same root as ὀργίζω as listed above.
- **θυμός** (thumos = [noun] an outburst of passion, wrath, rage), eg, Luke 4:28, Acts 19:28, Rom 2:8, 2 Cor 12:20, Gal 5:20, etc.  In English a person in such a state much be described as in a blind rage; ie, acting irrationally angry.

Here Paul is condemning uncontrolled outburst of anger and rage, quite correctly.